# Inactive or deactivated?

Tags: word-choice

Is it "inactive contacts", or "deactivated contacts"? My teacher told me that using "inactive contacts" is incorrect, and I should use "deactivated contacts" instead for the contacts who don't seem to be active in BBM (Blackberry Messenger). But which one do you think sounds better?

Comment: Inactive and deactivated have different meanings. It depends on what you mean.

Comment: Inactive contacts are those contacts which have been dormant for a particular amount of time.

Deactivated contacts are the ones which have been deactivated by someone for some reason.

They are different and should be used based on the intended meaning.

Comment: I've edited my questions, and thanks a lot for those who answered.

Comment: Looking at your edit, I would say you're right and your teacher's wrong. The contacts don't seem to be active, so they are inactive. That's the very definition of *inactive*. They have not been deactivated by you, they have become inactive by themselves. Additionally, in reply to Josh and Nagarajan, I would like to submit that deactivated contacts are also inactive. In fact that's what they are deactivated *for* in the first place. To become inactive.

Comment: The former contacts have obviously stopped being active, if only by their inactivity rather than some active step (resignation, say), but 'deactivated' would mean 'having been rendered inactive by some other agent' and is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Inactive & Deactivate** have a different meaning concerning the *cause* of such inactivity which is the common *effect* : no present activity.

*Deactivate* implies a **deactivation from an outside** operator. So it's impossible to become active again without a previous exterior intervention on purpose to allow a mutation.

*Inactive* is the simple inactivity that proceeds ***from*** the element itself which is no active (never or for a while) ; but it could become active without (detected) exogenous/alien influence.

As we put it, it's a question of degree or level more than nature because all depend of the type of the intervention ; IE. what could seem a *proprio motu* change in the cell at first sight could be indeed the product of an exterior enzyme.

Comment: ............huh?

Comment: There seems no Deactive word, only Deactivate?

Comment: Deactive is not a word.